# SEO - Does order of html carry importance - text before images preferred over opposite?

Tags: seo, markup

I have a two column layout with text to the left and a slideshow to the right. In order that I may float the text around the right column I would need to place the right column first with a right float. This means that I have all my images before the page text in my html.

It seems apparent that the search engine rank of a page for keywords is determined, at least mainly, by the text content of the page. Would the described order of html hurt my ranking?

I guess a bonus question would be how to float around a right column, see reddit for an example, though I think I should ask this on another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a microscopic level it might make a difference, but I would spend much more time worrying about things like your information architecture, server performance and the quality and quantity or links to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Text at top of code supposedly has more weight. (but google changes algorythms often)

( Can't you float left both (you can get the help of margin-left and right) ? or if you can go position absolute(I think you can do also with relative) and fixed widths using "left", etc, to position.  )

Comment: Thanks! I've asked the question stackoverflow about layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702676/wrap-text-around-right-floated-column-where-left-column-appears-first-in-html

Answer (score 1):

This used to be much more important than it is now. As long as your individual files aren't huge, everything's going to get indexed.

Make sure you look at how your pages look to Google. Search for cache:yourdomain.com and then click to see a text-only version in the upper right.

If it looks ridiculous or very wrong, fix it until it looks right.