# SEO - Listing Sidebar Code Before Content Code

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content, content

On my website, I have always ordered my code with the code for the sidebar coming first, then the navigation bar, then the content section (with the individual paragraphs, images, etc... specific to each page), and lastly the footer. By order, I simply mean the code for my sidebar is first in the HTML document.

The sidebar, navigation bar, and footer are all pretty much the same on all pages of the website. Is it bad that I am listing the duplicate content first? Should I be putting my content code first, because that is the part that is unique to each individual page? Does it matter what order code is listed in (especially for example if the navigation is absolute positioned and not within the flow of the document)?

**Edit** This is specific not only about the order of HTML code but also the influence of duplicate content within the order of HTML. It may be that text that comes first in an HTML document is more heavily weighted, but does duplicate content apply to that as well.

Comment: See also: [Does order of html carry importance - text before images preferred over opposite?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12405/seo-does-order-of-html-carry-importance-text-before-images-preferred-over-op)

Comment: When you have time to do it, move your navigation below the content. Google can recognize headers and navigation, but there IS a difference in performance moving the repetitive HTML below content as much as possible. The one answer was dated 2011 and was out of date even in 2011.